# How to connect eclipse to Jmeter

Tags: eclipse, jmeter

I am facing an issue of connecting eclipse to jmeter.
I try following this article http://p3lang.com/2016/03/configure-jmeter-in-eclipse/
that supposed to be step by step.
I am using jmeter 3.3 and downloaded oxygen eclipse.
 1. I created a java project
 2. "Import JMeter source into the recently created Java project"
 3. I Change the eclipse output folder

when I press the build.xml -> run as Ant build  I get error about Test.jtl does not exists
Moreover under source I do not see jmeter files
Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?
I their a step by step instruction to connect eclipse to jmeter?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you [downloaded](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) a wrong JMeter source that does not contain an `extras` folder.

**Use as source one of the following archives:**

- JMeter 3.3 (current version): [`apache-jmeter-3.3_src.zip`](http://mirror.23media.de/apache//jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-3.3_src.zip)
- JMeter 2.13 (as in the example): [`apache-jmeter-2.13_src.zip`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-2.13_src.zip)

Comment: is their a way to connect intellij instead?

Comment: @Bastian The Ant support is not so good in IntelliJ, but it should work with any Java IDE.

Comment: can you please specify what is the capabilities of using eclipse with Jmeter? Can I debug all my JSR223 samplers? or just to write the code of sampler and debug it?

Comment: @Bastian I don't know that. You might ask this in a separate question.